# Emoji typing regex messed up

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm building a simple chat with some basic emojis. So when the user for example types `:)`, a smiley emoji is being displayed inside the input field.

However my regex fails when it comes to the emoji `:/` and the reason is that it messes up URLs. (Keep in mind the emoji detection is triggered on keyup).

Example test text:

> Hello could you please visit my website at http://www.example.com or https://www.example.com :/ ://

So to sum up the regex must not replace `:/` when it starts with `http` or `https`.

Currently in my mapping I have this: `"[^http?s]:/{1}(?!/)": "1F615"` but for some strange reason it keeps 'eating the previous character upon replace'.

Comment: perhaps allow for whitespace?

Comment: the question is not clear can you add sample input and desired output

Comment: What you really need is a negative look-behind. Unfortunately, JavaScript regex doesn't support negative look-behind.

Comment: how are you executing your regexes? lookbehinds are not supported in JS RegExp so you can't define something as `x after but not including y` or `x but not after y` in a RegExp. You have to filter the occurances you want/not want yourself.

Comment: `:/(?!/)` should probably suffice, to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```js
function reverse(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}
function getMatch(str){
 const regex = /\/+\:(?!s{0,1}ptth)/g;
 const subst = ``;
 const result = reverse(reverse(str).replace(regex, subst));
 console.log(result);
}


getMatch(`Hello could you please visit my website at http://www.example.com or https://www.example.com :/ ://`);
```

Since Javascript does not support negative lookbehind, but does support negative lookaheads, we use this to our advantage by reversing the string, replacing and then reversing again

[demo for reversed string](https://regex101.com/r/Bao3s8/1)

Comment: its pretty close as you can see it detects " :/" i'd like not to include the space in the begining. I'm facing the exact same issue with the sapce

Comment: what do you mean, I didn't get you

Comment: Uhhh... that regex does not do what you think it does... https://regex101.com/r/YwwQDa/1

Comment: The matches include a space in the begining as you can see in your demo. If I replace something like that with an emoji is will replace ' :/' and not ':/'

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanks for pointing out my mistake, not sure how it was working :P

Answer (score 1):

Since the issue is that `:/` is messing up `http://`, and JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds ("check if this did/didn't occur immediately before"), I think the simplest solution would be just to check if the `:/` is (not) followed by another `/`

```
":/(?!/)" : "1F615"
```

Notably, the lookahead (which *is* supported by JavaScript) does not actually match the subsequent `/`, it just ensures that it isn't there.

Comment: You are corrent that is what I thought also, but the issue is that the regex replacing occurs on keyup. So when a user types 'http:/' it will trigger the replace before the last '/' gets typed

Comment: how about reversing the string and doing a negative look ahead, replace and then reverse again ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be ":\/(?!\/)" ?

Comment: @Syd That complicates things a bit, and generally speaking I would highly advise against such things, but if you can differentiate between `keyup` and `change` (ie. typing is complete) then you can use `":/(?=[^/])"` in the `keyup` event (lookahead ensures there is any character other than another `/`) and `":/(?=[^/]|$)"` in the `change` event (lookahead additionally accepts `:/` at the end of the text). Honestly I dislike emoji replacers in the first place. If I wanted  then I would type , whereas if I type :/ then I probably want :/

Comment: @JuanFerrer You don't need to escape `/` if you are passing it to `new RegExp()` (which I'm assuming is the case, since the map uses strings)